# jQuery Driven Image Slider Headache

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-plugins

I have been trying to figure out a problem for about 3 hours now and really can't understand why this plugin is not working. The plugin in question is called Blueberry and is an image slider using jQuery.

The plugin works perfectly from the demo folder (running locally). But when I try to copy and paste the code over to my working website it only shows the bullet points but does not show the main image.

- All of the stylesheets and javascript files are included in the right order
- The images are opening correctly when clicking the link from the source code
- The stylesheets and javascript are also still working when clicked from the source code
- The markup is correct in the HTML side of things

Below is the source code for my site. Assume all the links work and are in the correct directory.

(I really try not to advertise but I cannot post this much source code, the source code in question is here. http://web.zesty-designs.co.uk)

Thanks very much in advance for reading this question.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'blueberry'  in console errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://web.zesty-designs.co.uk/public/packages/blueberry/jquery.blueberry.js">
```

You have to have

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://web.zesty-designs.co.uk/public/packages/blueberry/jquery.blueberry.js"></script>
```

Browser outputs error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'blueberry'`.

It means there is no such object, so you have JS called in css style...

Comment: Cannot believe I made such a stupid mistake. Thanks for the help. This is why I posted the question so I could get a second look over!

Comment: @BradBird Try using a web developer console next time, it’s much faster than posting a question each time you have a JS error :)

Comment: I honestly did not think of that. I normally use the Chrome debugger but thanks for the sound advice :).

Answer (score 0):

The console window reads this error on your site:

```
         Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'blueberry'
```

Take a look at your JavaScript and make sure your script is being loaded in correctly.